# Change color of an element only when another one is on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

hi i have a list of 5 p elements, they have teal background and i want that
when i hover the second element, the second itself and the fourth, will change the text color to orange. and go back to the normal color when the second is not on hover.

```
<p id="t1"> test 1 </p>
<p id="t2"> test 2 </p>
<p id="t3"> test 3 </p>
<p id="t4"> test 4 </p>
<p id="t5"> test 5 </p>

p {
    background-color: teal;
    width: 100px;
}

p#t1:hover {
  color: yellow;
}


$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("p#t2").hover(
      function() {
        $("p#t2").style("color", "orange");
        $("p#t4").style("color", "orange");
      },
      function() {
        $("p#t2").style("color", "black");
        $("p#t4").style("color", "black");
      }
    );
  });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPOgPG

this is my code... 
what's wrong?

Comment: are you trying this http://jsfiddle.net/jrbj72ho/ ?

Comment: tnx, why that is not working on codepen? i changed style to css... but doesn't work there

Comment: You didn't include the Jquery library in your CodePen example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVYwRw

Comment: if that's working for you @Michael, let me add that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

`style` is a DOM function. You want `css()` for jQuery.

Also, for the element you are hovering over, you could make a css `:hover` class for that color to reduce the jQuery to just the other element.

```
p#t2:hover { color:black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Style is not property

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p#t2").hover(
      function() {
        $("p#t2, p#t4").css("color", "orange");
      },
      function() {
        $("p#t2, p#t4").css("color", "black");
      }
    );
});
```